# Changing serial Number to customized date form in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors. One of them is the quarterly GDP, while the other is the corresponding Quarter in serial date number form. Now I would like to combine these two vectors to one matrix and change the serial numbers to e.g. "Q1-2007", etc. 
To give an example:

```
GDP = [100 120 130 120].';
quarters = [714781 714871 714962 715054].';

output = datestr(quarters, 'QQ yyyy');  % change  serial date format
```

Now I would like to create a 4x2 matrix out of the two vectors 'GDP' and 'output', but this doesn't work. Do I have to change my serial datenumber differently? or is there a way how this works out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's rather difficult to say without seeing your matrix and code. Please read up on [ask] and [mcve], then [edit] the question to contain a (sample) of your matrix and the (non-working) code you already wrote. Please explain why it doesn't work and what the expected output is. We are willing to help you, but are not clairvoyant.

Comment: `GDP` is of type `double` and `output` is of type `string`, You cannot combine 2 different data type in the same matrix. (Note that your date serial number were `double` in the first place, so you could combine that with your GDP values.) If your are ready to let go of the _matrix_ restriction, you could combine the two parameter in a [cell array](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the [help page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) on `datestr`?

From your vague description it seems the following *might* be what you are after

```
datestr(dateVector, 'QQ yyyy')
```

or alternatively something like `datestr(now, 27)` which would return `'Q4-2019'`